# Android: Getting incorrect CheckBox value from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, checkbox, sharedpreferences

In my mainActivity I'm trying to read the value of a checkbox in another activity. I however seem to get the opposite of what the value actually is. I suspect the problem is that I'm trying to get the value before I've opened the activity containing the checkbox.

In my mainActivity I have a

```
  public boolean checkValue;
```

that I want to give the value of the checkbox in the other activity like this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkValue = SettingsActivity.getCheckValue(); 
}
```

which I later use like this

```
 public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String >{
...
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        checkValue = SettingsActivity.getCheckValue();

        if(checkValue != true) {
               TextView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
                TextView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   

        }
```

The other activity looks like this

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static CheckBox checkBox1;

public static boolean checkStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);;




    loadSavedPreferences();
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox1.isChecked());


    checkStatus = checkBox1.isChecked();


}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", true);

    if (checkBoxValue) {
        checkBox1.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox1.setChecked(false);
    }


}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}




@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());


}

public static Boolean getCheckValue(){
    return checkStatus;
}
```

I suspect a solution could be to initialize the settingActivity before opening it in the app, not sure if this is possible though.

Comment: Couple of points to note -
1) Should probably store the checked value in SharedPreferences, and read it later

or

2) Start SettingsActivity via startActivityForResult(), and get the value of the checkbox in OnActivityResult callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. If you call getCheckValue before creating your activity, you are just going to get the default value of your static variable checkStatus. 
Usually you don't want to mix your logic with your UI.
Why not getting the correct value directly from your shared preference?
You are already doing that in loadSavedPreferences().

Instead of calling `checkValue = SettingsActivity.getCheckValue();`

Call:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
ceckValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however when I do this checkValue always shows up as false. Any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: Alright while I'm not sure why it works exactly, but changing the **true** at the end of checkValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", true); to **false** solved the problem for me!